# Maven Plugin puts -d32 -XstartOnFirstThread in GWT launch file on a Mac

Tags: java, gwt, maven-plugin

Using Maven M2 Plugin from Sonatype on a Mac. Unfortunately every time I run Maven to "Update Project Configuration" it modifies my-app-hosted.launch file by putting "-d32 -XstartOnFirstThread" in VM_ARGUMENTS. This messes up the .launch file and makes it unusable for anyone on Windows who needs to run the app.

I'd like to figure out a way to disable putting of both options in VM_ARGS. Having spent numerous hours online I've failed to find the answer.

I am running 64-bit Eclipse on a Mac. startOnFirstThread option should not even be used now, since hosted GWT no longer uses SWT but Swing.

Comment: Your using this as well ? http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you are looking for, but have you considered not adding to version control / sharing the launch files between developers? Just adding them to svn:ignore or .gitignore instead?